# returning interface explicit conversion

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, implicit-conversion

I have the following interface

```
public interface INegocio<T> where T : DTOBaseEntity, new()
{
    T GetByKey(object id);
    T Save(T dto);
    void Delete(T dto);
    DTOCollection<T> GetAll();
    void SetStateBDE(T dto, int estado, int tipoEvento, string descripcion = null);
    void SetStateBDE(T dto, int estado);
}
```

Then I have the following abstract class that implements the interface and more

```
 public abstract class NegocioBase<T, S> : INegocio<T>
    where T : DTOBaseEntity, new()
    where S : ObjetoXPOBase
{
    #region - Properties -
    private Session _sesionActual;
    protected Session SesionActual
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_sesionActual == null) || (_sesionActual.Connection == null) || !_sesionActual.IsConnected)
            {
                _sesionActual = XpoHelper.GetNewSession();
                _sesionActual.TrackPropertiesModifications = true;
            }

            return _sesionActual;
        }
        set
        {
            _sesionActual = value;
        }
    }        
    #endregion

    #region - Constructor -
    protected NegocioBase(Session session)
    {
        _sesionActual = session;
    }
    protected NegocioBase()
    {
        _sesionActual = XpoHelper.GetNewSession();
    }
    #endregion

    #region - GetByKey -
    public T GetByKey(object id)
    {
        S miXpo = XpoHelper.GetClassByKey<S>(id, SesionActual);
        if (miXpo == null)
            return null;
        else
            return miXpo.ToDTO<T>();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene las entidades que se encuentran entre los números desde y hasta bajo la consulta q
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="q"></param>
    /// <param name="desde"></param>
    /// <param name="hasta"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected DTOCollection<T> GetPaging(XPQuery<S> q, int desde, int hasta)
    {
        if (desde > 0 || hasta > 0)
            return q.Skip(desde).Take(hasta).ToList().ToDTO<S, T>();
        return q.ToList().ToDTO<S, T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene las entidades que se encuentran entre los números desde y hasta bajo la consulta q
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="q"></param>
    /// <param name="desde"></param>
    /// <param name="hasta"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected DTOCollection<T> GetPaging(IEnumerable<S> q, int desde, int hasta)
    {
        if (desde > 0 || hasta > 0)
            return q.Skip(desde).Take(hasta).ToList().ToDTO<S, T>();
        return q.ToList().ToDTO<S, T>();
    }
    #region - GetAll -
    public DTOCollection<T> GetAll()
    {
        var data = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                    select x);                       
        var dto = data.ToList<S>().ToDTO<S, T>();
        return dto;
    }        

    #endregion             

    #region - Get Methods -
    public T GetMax()
    {
        var max = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                   select x).Max().ToDTO<T>();
        return max;
    }
    public T GetMin()
    {
        var max = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                   select x).Min().ToDTO<T>();
        return max;
    }

    public T GetPrevious(T current)
    {
        var previous = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                        select x).LastOrDefault(p => p.GetKeyValue().ConvertToInt32() < current.PrimaryKeyValue.ConvertToInt32());
        return previous.ToDTO<T>();
    }
    public T GetNext(T current)
    {
        var next = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                        select x).FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetKeyValue().ConvertToInt32() > current.PrimaryKeyValue.ConvertToInt32());
        return next.ToDTO<T>();
    }
    public T GetLast()
    {
        var data = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                    select x).LastOrDefault();
        return data.ToDTO<T>();
    }

    public T GetFirst()
    {
        var data = (from x in SesionActual.Query<S>()
                    select x).FirstOrDefault();
        return data.ToDTO<T>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region - Save & Delete -
    protected virtual bool SaveValidation(T dto)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public T Save(T dto)
    {
        SaveValidation(dto);
        S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
        xpo.Save();
        T Midto = xpo.ToDTO<T>();
        return Midto;
    }
    public T Save(ref T dto)
    {
        SaveValidation(dto);
        S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
        xpo.Save();
        dto = xpo.ToDTO<T>();
        return dto;
    }

    public void Save(DTOCollection<T> dtos)
    {
        foreach (T item in dtos.GetDeletedItems())
        {
            Delete(item);
        }
        foreach (T item in dtos)
        {
            Save(item);
        }
    }
    public T SaveValidateDuplicate(T dto, string mensaje = "", string titulo = "error")
    {
        try
        {
            SaveValidation(dto);
            S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
            xpo.Save();
            T Midto = xpo.ToDTO<T>();
            return Midto;
        }
        catch (ConstraintViolationException)
        {
            throw new InfoException(titulo, "Error de datos duplicados. " + mensaje);
        }
    }


    public void Delete(T dto)
    {
        S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
        xpo.Delete();
    }
    #endregion

    #region - BDE States -

    private EstrategiaEstado GetBDEStrategy(string factory)
    {
        EstrategiaEstado miEstrategia = null;
        string nombreClase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[factory];
        Type t = Type.GetType(nombreClase);
        miEstrategia = (EstrategiaEstado)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        return miEstrategia;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Cambiar de estado.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"></param>
    /// <param name="estado"></param>
    public void SetStateBDE(T dto, int estado)
    {
        S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
        if (xpo is EntidadConEstado)
        {
            EntidadConEstado bdeXPO = xpo as EntidadConEstado;
            EstrategiaEstado estrategia = GetBDEStrategy(bdeXPO.TipoFactory);
            estrategia.obtenerInstancia().EstablecerEstado(bdeXPO, estado);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Cambiar de estado y generar evento.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dto"></param>
    /// <param name="estado"></param>
    /// <param name="tipoEvento"></param>
    /// <param name="Descripcion"></param>
    public void SetStateBDE(T dto, int estado, int tipoEvento, string descripcion = null)
    {
        S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
        if (xpo is EntidadConEstado)
        {
            EntidadConEstado bdeXPO = xpo as EntidadConEstado;
            EstrategiaEstado estrategia = GetBDEStrategy(bdeXPO.TipoFactory);
            estrategia.obtenerInstancia().EstablecerEstado(bdeXPO, estado);
        }            
    }        
    public int GetStateBDEOf(T dto)
    {
        int estado = 0;
        if (dto == null) return estado;
        S xpo = dto.ToXpo<S>(SesionActual);
        if (xpo is EntidadConEstado)
        {
            EntidadConEstado bdeXPO = xpo as EntidadConEstado;
            BinaryOperator filtroEntidad = new BinaryOperator("IdEntidad", bdeXPO.IdEntidad);
            BinaryOperator filtroInstanciaEntidad = new BinaryOperator("IdInstanciaEntidad", dto.PrimaryKeyValue.ConvertToInt32());
            CriteriaOperator filter = new GroupOperator(filtroEntidad, filtroInstanciaEntidad);
            BDE_EstadoInstanciaEntidad miEstadoInstancia = (BDE_EstadoInstanciaEntidad)SesionActual.FindObject(typeof(BDE_EstadoInstanciaEntidad), filter);
            if (miEstadoInstancia != null) //Si no llega a tener estado y es necesario, se lo creo
            {
                estado = miEstadoInstancia.IdEstado;
            }
        }
        return estado;

    }
    public int GetStateBDEOf(object id)
    {
        T dto = GetByKey(id);
        return GetStateBDEOf(dto);
    }
```

And finally I have a class that inherits from NegocioBase.

```
public class SiniestroNegocio : NegocioBase<DTO_Siniestro, Siniestro>
{
    public SiniestroNegocio(Session session) : base(session) { }      
}
```

Of course DTO_Siniestro inherits from DTOBaseEntity and Siniestro inherits from ObjetoXPOBase.

What I am trying to do is a Factory to return the "Negocio" that I want like this.

```
 private static INegocio<DTOBaseEntity> GetNegocio(int idEntidad, Session sesion) 
    {
        switch (idEntidad)
        {
            case 4:
                return new SiniestroNegocio(sesion);
            default:
                return null;                    
        }            
    }
```

This is not compiling, it say that I can not implicit convert that I have an explicit conversion. And when I make an explicit conversion with some cast, it throws an exception. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out. I had to take off generics from the interface and implement it in an explicit way in the abstract class like this.

```
public interface INegocio
{
    DTOBaseEntity GetByKey(object id);
    DTOBaseEntity Save(DTOBaseEntity dto);
    void Delete(DTOBaseEntity dto);        
    void SetStateBDE(DTOBaseEntity dto, int estado, int tipoEvento, string descripcion = null);
    void SetStateBDE(DTOBaseEntity dto, int estado);
}
```

Then the explicit way like this inside the abstract class

```
    DTOBaseEntity INegocio.GetByKey(object id)
    {
        return this.GetByKey(id);
    }

    DTOBaseEntity INegocio.Save(DTOBaseEntity dto)
    {
        return this.Save((T)dto);
    }

    void INegocio.Delete(DTOBaseEntity dto)
    {
        this.Delete((T)dto);
    }

    void INegocio.SetStateBDE(DTOBaseEntity dto, int estado, int tipoEvento, string descripcion)
    {
        this.SetStateBDE((T)dto, estado, tipoEvento, descripcion);
    }

    void INegocio.SetStateBDE(DTOBaseEntity dto, int estado)
    {
        this.SetStateBDE((T)dto, estado);
    }
```

then in the factory we can return something of INegocio type.

```
 private static INegocio GetNegocio(int idEntidad, Session sesion) 
    {
        switch (idEntidad)
        {
            case 4:
                return new SiniestroNegocio(sesion);
            default:
                return null;                   
        }            
    }
```